# Most efficient way to find whether a list contains a duplicate or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have a `list` of integers of large size given as input.
I want to write a function to check whether the items in the list are all distinct or not.

**Approach 1**: Iterate over the list and keep track of all the items encountered so far using a `set`. Return `True` as soon as a duplicate is encountered.

```
def containsDuplicates1(a):
    seen = set()                                
    for i in a:                                 
        if i in seen:
            return True

        seen.add(i)         

     return False
```

Time Complexity: O(n)
Space Complexity: O(n)

**Approach 2:** Convert the entire list to a `set` and compare their lengths.

```
def containsDuplicates2(a):
    return len(a) != len(set(a))
```

Time Complexity: O(n) (for `set(a)` operation)
Space Complexity: O(n)

The First Approach performs better than the second approach when it is likely that the given list contains duplicates.

Is this the best we can do? Or is there a more efficient way in either time or space to solve this problem?

P.S: I have read all the related questions on Stack Overflow and none of them discuss the efficiency aspect of the problem. Hence, I have asked it here.

Comment: What does "perform better" mean in this context?

Comment: no, you can't - in terms of big O, you must traverse thw entire list in the worst case (no duplicates)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque "perform better" means that the first approach solves the problem optimally both in terms of speed and space.

Comment: Yes, I thought your comment was a reply to my earlier question

Comment: Also note that If the number of elements is very large `in` may not give O(1) in case of Approach 1. reference: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @venky__ I had almost forgotten about this. However, the wiki doesn't mention what are the worst case scenarios for the `in` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you do this in time or space complexity smaller than O(n)?

In a word, no.

Consider the case where all elements are distinct. To establish that this is the case, you need to look at every element at least once. This requires O(n) time.

If there are no constraints on the values that the elements can take, you need to store all elements you've seen so far in order to check future elements against what you've seen. If all elements are distinct, this requires O(n) memory.

Comment: Not my downvote, this is a legitimate answer to the question - it is not possible. The only thing you can do is reduce the constant associated the `n`, but it still remains linear.